# Sharepoint 2013: accessing data from People Picker inputs (JSON)

Tags: jquery, json, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint 2013 client people picker. It returns the following structure:

```
 <input id="peoplePickerDiv1_TopSpan_HiddenInput" name="peoplePickerDiv1_TopSpan_HiddenInput" type="hidden" value="
[{&quot;Key&quot;:&quot;i:0#.w|XXXXX\\tkabcs&quot;,&quot;Description&quot;
:&quot;XXXXX\\tkabcs&quot;,&quot;DisplayText&quot;
:&quot;ABCDE, ABC-DEF&quot;,&quot;EntityType&quot;:&quot;User&quot;
,&quot;ProviderDisplayName&quot;:&quot;Active Directory&quot;,&quot;ProviderName&quot;:&quot;AD&quot;,&quot;IsResolved&quot;
    :true,&quot;EntityData&quot;:,&quot;MultipleMatches&quot;:}]">
```

How can I access stuff like the "Key" in the value attribute?

(Sorry for the bad structure, had to take it from a console log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That input's value looks like JSON, except it has two syntax errors near the end of the string.  I had to change:

```
EntityData&quot;:,&quot;MultipleMatches&quot;:}]
```

to:

```
EntityData&quot;:&quot;MultipleMatches&quot;}]
```

(removing an extra , and : )

With those changes, I was able to parse the string to an object and access the Key.

```
var valJson = $('#peoplePickerDiv1_TopSpan_HiddenInput').val();
var parsed = $.parseJSON(valJson);
console.log(parsed[0].Key);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t39toe9m/).

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Will try in a sec, looks very good though!